# Mac Terminal Git + Less doesn't show the first line of output

Tags: terminal, git, macos, less

I have problems with `git` and `less` commands output in the standard Mac `Terminal` app.

For some reason, when I do `git log` or something else requiring `less`, it always skips the first line of output. There is no way to see it.

In older OS versions I used to resize the `Terminal` window back and forth and the first line appeared eventually. But now this trick was "fixed" and `Terminal` output rendering remains the same when you resize.

Pure `less` call without `git` works fine. I can do `cat file | less` and I can see the first line.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out I had the following in `.gitconfig`

```
[core]
    pager = less -r
```

When I removed this, `less` started showing the first line correctly.

Comment: Omg thank you!!